# Convert function to Simulink block

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

How do I convert from a function, that I have written as an m-file, into a block in a Simulink model?

Answer (score 3):

There's a video [here](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/incorporating-matlab-algorithms-into-a-simulink-model-69028.html) that shows some options. Basically, use the [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block. Or, if you want to keep the code separate (and don't care about code generation), you can use the [MATLAB Interpreted Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html) block.