# How can I call an m file in Simulink and put it to a block in my model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I call an m file in Simulink and put it to a block in my model (without using an S function)? Does anybody have an idea? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think this was already asked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225248/matlab-convert-function-to-simulink-block

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to apply a user-defined MATLAB function to Simulink signals, there are a few different ways to do this, depending on your objective. All options are available within the [User-Defined Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f4-4889.html#f4-5797) section of the Simulink library.

- Use the [MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block if you intend to generate code from your model. This block does have restrictions, the entire gamut of built-in MATLAB functions is not available.
- Use the [Interpreted MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html) block if you don't care about code generation, this block can make use of any functions.
- Use the [Fcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/fcn.html) block if your m-file is trivial and contains a simple expression operating on the inputs. In this case you can type the expression directly into the block dialog and reference the input / output signals as shown in the documentation.

Comment: When would you use S functions? I know people use them, but what are their advantages? Thanks for the big picture by the way.

Comment: @KE. I'm not sure when you would pick an m-file S-function over one of the approaches listed above. But if you mean C S-functions, those mostly come in handy when you you're dealing with code generation. In that case you'd create a non-inlined S-function that models simulation behavior as you want it to, and then create the parts that go into generated code in TLC. You can also create an inlined S-function that shares the simulation and code generation code, but I've found these to be of limited use. Also, C S-functions can be significantly faster than m-file S-functions and the options above.

Comment: Thanks! I don't generate code so I will stick to the other options.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Fcn block is the best solution to embed M-function file into Simulink model. However, be cautious which version of MATLAB you are using, e.g., with later versions of MATLAB Function Block can be implemented with M-function file with %#codegen and C compiler need to be with your MATLAB package. Good luck